# Problemas con php mail()

Tags: php, html

Este es mi código, tal parece que se ejecuta, pero no recibo ningún mail, estoy ejecutando en server con windows, php 5.3

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <title>Pruebas</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <form action="enviar.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="formNombre" placeholder="nombre">
            <input type="email" name="formCorreo" placeholder="correo">
            <input type="tel" name="formTelefono" placeholder="telefono">
            <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </body>


    
    </html>
```

```
<?php

$nombre = $_POST ["formNombre"];
$correo = $_POST ["formCorreo"];
$telefono = $_POST ["formTelefono"];

$destino = "ana@herz.mx";
$asunto = "Contacto de $nombre";
$mensaje = "Hola soy $nombre y este es mi teléfono $telefono";

$cabeceras = "From: $correo";

if (mail($destino, $asunto, $mensaje, $cabeceras))
{
    echo("Correo enviado");
}
else
{
    echo("Error en el envío");
}


?>
```

Comment: ¿Te da algún error?

Comment: No, ninguno, sólo no me llega el mail, pero sí muestra: "Correo enviado"

Comment: ¿Revisaste la carpeta Spam o correo no deseado para ver si está ahí?

Comment: No, no están en spam, lo he hecho mil veces, en 2 host diferentes, uno con windows y uno con linux, enviando a correos comerciales y de dominio,y nada que funciona. ;(

Answer (score 1):

Hola amigo mira yo tenia el mismo problema hace unos dias y yrnia un codigo muy similar, yo te recomiendo que subas tu codigo a un hosting  yo uso hostinger para preubas yo te lo recomiendo mucho si solo quieres hacer pruebas, tu codigo esta correcto,el problema sera tu servidor local si usas XAMPP es un problema  muy tipico que no se envien te recomiendo que uses hostinger.

Mi codigo es este lo puede adaptar a tu necesidades:

```html
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "gilbertoquintero656@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "Lovi acabados";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " Te a enviado este mensaje : " . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender

    echo "Gracias por enviarnos tu mensaje" . $first_name . ", Nos contactaremos lo mas pronto contigo.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }
?>
```

[Este es el link de hostinger](http://hostinger.mx/)

Comment: Estoy haciendo pruebas en host y ni así funciona.

Comment: An Herz en cual host?

Comment: Puedes probar mi codigo amiga.

Answer (score 0):

El problema puede presentarse porque tu computadora o servidor no tiene configurado un servidor SMTP

El codigo esta correcto creo que ese puede ser el error.

Si PHP no te da error verifica habilitando se muestren los mismos modificando el php.ini

Busca:

```
display_errors = Off
```

Cambiala por:

```
display_errors = On
```

Y reinicia Apache esto servira para que se pueda ver algun error adicional.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer envio de correo electronico debes tener un servicio que lo realice, en linux se usa postfix u otros, estos se encargan de hacer el envio. La clase de phpmail devuelve ok por que hace su parte pero el correo no llega por que no existe el servicio que se encargue de ello. Si tu app la vas a desplegar en un servidor linux, mi recomendacion es que uses vagrant y no xampp, te permite tener un entorno similar al de produccion y minimizar este tipo de errores.